# Is there an alternative to OSMDROID?

Tags: android, osmdroid

When using multitouch for zooming, osmdroid doesn't behave correctly.
Also I've found some source code inside the jar file that uses a different license and therefore I am not sure I can use it.

Comment: are you trying to avoid google maps?

Answer (score 3):

There is Mapsforge.  I believe the latest version dropped online support, but you may be able to still use it.  I'm not sure on the licensing for you situation though.

http://code.google.com/p/mapsforge/

These 2 are the only FREE libraries for OpenStreetMaps AFAIK.

Comment: thanks, actually mapsforge user experience for scrolling and zooming is much better than osmdroid. However it is also under LGPL so I cannot use it :(

Comment: Why can you not use LGPL?  My understanding is under this license you my use mapsforge in a commercial app and your app does not have to be open source.  You must give credit to mapsforge.

Comment: For what I have been told, if I modify osmdroid/mapsforge then I must share these modifications with the community. I have to open source my code. And that's not a choice right now.

Answer (score 1):

You've already found osmdroid.

There is google's api Which isn't on some devices (nook, fire) :
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/

There is bing for android : 
http://bingmapsandroidsdk.codeplex.com/

And also mapforge (based on openstreetmaps)
http://code.google.com/p/mapsforge/

Comment: There is also Nutiteq, is free if you use it with OpenStreetMap, even for commercial applications. See github.com/nutiteq/hellomap3d/wiki/Free-openstreetmap-license

Comment: you suggest Nutiteq. Is that you've some projects using it? Anyway, how to take your own map and then use the marker on it via nutiteq @tomasbarrios... ? i encountered some error here while using it.

Answer (score 1):

There's also mapquest.
The biggest problem with all alternatives to Google API is that all maps are unreadably small on HDPI+ screen's.

Comment: I am having this issue too.  One option is mapsforge.  You can set the text size for offline maps.  There may be a way to change the textsize on cloudmade maps if you have an account with them also.

Answer (score 0):

Nutiteq : https://github.com/nutiteq/hellomap3d

You can add your own map.
Different tile sources.

Comment: can you provide the step by step....? @MartijnM... the article https://github.com/nutiteq/hellomap3d/wiki/Offline-map-tiles seems not giving the detail steps of how to create the map, and which map format that supported by nutiteq, and also...

Comment: Just use tilemill from Mapbox. It creates a mbtiles file that you can use in Nutiteq.

Comment: Nutiteq has joined Carto. They offer 30 day trial. https://github.com/CartoDB/mobile-android-samples/